# Could not find image named 'ToolbarArrangeByTemplate'

Tags: nssavepanel

I'm systematically gets this error in the log pane of Xcode, saying:
Could not find image named 'ToolbarArrangeByTemplate'
each time a NSOpenPanel or NSSavePanel is run.

Does anybody gets the same message? It seems to be an issue in Xcode 4.3.2. Internet does not bring anything relevant. This name is not referenced in the docs.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, but only if I run my app in german, which is the only localization besides english (native development region is english).

Comment: Right, ogott: when run in english, no problem, but as soon I've localized the app in french, this message appears.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same message in localized versions of my apps, even in Xcode 4.3.3.

Here’s the image, in its button, from the Open/Save panel:

[image: The ToolbarArrangeByTemplate image in its open/save panel button.]

It seems that Apple inadvertently set that image as localized but didn’t add any localization.
It’s obviously an error as it is a pictogram icon that doesn’t need any localization at all…

Let’s hope Apple fixes it in Mountain Lion. Someone should file a bug here… However this is of no harm, it’s just polluting a little our logs and our users’…